# How to convert the application in j2me into j2me-polish?

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish, mobile-application

I develop a mobile application which is pure J2ME.But now the requirement is changed for J2me-polish.But i does not know J2me-polish.SUggest me good J2me-Polish tutorial.How to covert the application from J2me to J2me-Polish (Without changing in code is possible or not).

Thanks & Regards,
Sivakumar

Answer (score 0):

Here are some useful links from J2ME polish's official website:

1. [Installing J2ME polish](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/installation.html)
2. [Migrating J2ME polish](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/installation/migration.html)
3. [Designing with J2ME polish](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/design.html)
4. [Visual guide for J2ME polish](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/design/visual-guide.html)
5. [J2ME polish documentations](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/)

> Without changing in code is possible
>   or not?

You have to write some code to support J2ME polish. But may not require to change in code for functionalities. For designing GUI you have to made some changes in code and have to add some more coding.